# Unable to compile with Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm giving JetBrains IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4 a spin and have run into an issue when compiling programs.
When I run a program I get the following error:

```
Internal error: (java.io.FileNotFoundException) \domain.local\usersfolders\roberth\.IntelliJIdea12\system\compile-server\hibernate_test_1ad22f80\timestamps\data (The system cannot find the path specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \domain.local\usersfolders\roberth\.IntelliJIdea12\system\compile-server\hibernate_test_1ad22f80\timestamps\data (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resizeFile(PagedFileStorage.java:324)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resize(PagedFileStorage.java:308)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.resize(ResizeableMappedFile.java:72)
    at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.<init>(ResizeableMappedFile.java:46)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:76)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:38)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:31)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:137)
    at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:122)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.<init>(AbstractStateStorage.java:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.TimestampStorage.<init>(TimestampStorage.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectTimestamps.<init>(ProjectTimestamps.java:21)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:181)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:102)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This occurs with both `Run` and `Debug`. What setting do I need to change to correct the paths used to change them to my local classpaths and directories?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems that your user home is located on a network drive, which is [unsupported by IntelliJ](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-181)

> In some environments user's home directory is located on the mapped network drive which is unacceptable for IntelliJ IDEA. You'll notice the huge performance degradation. You may also want to move system directory to the faster or larger drive partition.

You should copy `IDEA_HOME\bin\idea.properties` to your home directory and adjust the following paths so that they point to local directories instead:

- idea.config.path
- idea.system.path
- idea.plugins.path

See the above link for further details. If you don't want to lose everything you already configured, just move `\domain.local\usersfolders\roberth\.IntelliJIdea12` to a local folder.

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I needed to know, but couldn't find. Thanks :)

Comment: I've modified idea.properties (in bin) *and* copied it to home. Still the build insists on giving this error.

Answer (score 5):

i got the below error in windows env:

Error:Internal error: (com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase$CorruptedException) PersistentEnumerator storage corrupted C:\Users>.IntelliJIdea14\system\compile-server\cmx_cdc441bb\aj\aspect_path.dat

and deleted the .dat file located at the above path and my jetbrain IDE started compiling all the classes and problem got resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar issue was not able to reload the compiled classes while debugging a program. Read a few blogs and deleted the compile and compile-server directories under `C:/Users/<yourUsername>/.IntelliJIdea<version>/system` and I could continue to use class reloading as usual.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. So I edited the **IDEA_HOME\bin\idea.properties** file and uncommented:

- idea.config.path
- idea.system.path
- idea.plugins.path
- idea.log.path

Then I removed the `${user.home}` from the `idea.config.path` and `idea.system.path` and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps worked for me:

1. Close IntelliJ IDEA
2. Edit **IDEA_HOME\bin\idea.properties** to contain the following lines:

   ```
   idea.config.path=C:/Users/<yourUsername>/.IdeaIC/config
   idea.system.path=C:/Users/<yourUsername>/.IdeaIC/system
   ```
3. Open IntelliJ IDEA

   - now the **.IdeaIC** folder (specified above) is created automatically and it has the following structure:

     ```
     .IdeaIC
        - config
        - system
     ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with OSX. What I did is just recreate the directory where IntelliJ caches compiled classes.

Answer (score 0):

This Error may encounter in IntellijIdea if you try to use some language-specific keywords as your class name or object name. In my case once I got a similar kind of error on using the reserved keywords.

Some options to fix the issue:

- Look for the language-specific keyword usage as a class/object name in your codebase.
- Try to invalidate the cache and restart from the File Menu
- Reimport the project from the source by recreating the .idea directory.