# Unable to compile with Android Studio 0.2.4 on Win7 x64

Tags: windows, android-studio

When I try to compile in Android Studio 0.2.4 I get an error like this:

```
Internal error: (java.io.FileNotFoundException) \archivos\virtualizados\apoloduvalis\.AndroidStudioPreview\system\compile-server\hibernate_test_1ad22f80\timestamps\data (The system cannot find the path specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \archivos\virtualizados\apoloduvalis\.AndroidStudioPreview\system\compile-server\hibernate_test_1ad22f80\timestamps\data (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:233)
at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resizeFile(PagedFileStorage.java:324)
at com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resize(PagedFileStorage.java:308)
at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.resize(ResizeableMappedFile.java:72)
at com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.<init>(ResizeableMappedFile.java:46)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:76)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:38)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:31)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:137)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentHashMap.<init>(PersistentHashMap.java:133)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.createMap(AbstractStateStorage.java:122)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.AbstractStateStorage.<init>(AbstractStateStorage.java:27)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.TimestampStorage.<init>(TimestampStorage.java:21)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.storage.ProjectTimestamps.<init>(ProjectTimestamps.java:21)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:90)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:181)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:102)
at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:107)
at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:26)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Finally I managed to get Gradle to work but when Android Studio tries to compile, it gets stuck on this exception. I am using Android Studio 0.2.4 (up to date version) on Win7 x64. ¿Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just found that you must configure Android Studio's path. It seems ItelliJ IDEA doesn't support network locations such as my user home:  [adjust the following paths so that they point to local directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15387202/888367)