# Importing a project from VCS: the system cannot find the path specified

Tags: git, intellij-idea, android-studio

I can't clone a repository using Android Studio/Intellij-Idea due to the error seen below in the green box.  I have configured Git and the test of it succeeds.  The confusing thing is I just installed IntelliJ and Git on another machine and was able to clone the same repository using the same steps last night.  I updated Android studio to the latest in the stable channel and also downloaded the latest version of git.

If I use the command line I can clone the repository as well as push but not from inside IntelliJ, any ideas what's going on?

[image: The problem]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check what the Android studio path is set to in IntelliJ.

It has been reported that [network paths are not well supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15387202/6309), local (c:...) paths are.